# UITextField with user text + static mark

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have an UITextField which user sets its luggage weight as numbers in TextField. I want to set that textfields value with weight mark (for ex 10 KG which comes from user settings) so whatever user types, there will be KG mark at the end of its textfield. Is there any way for it?

Comment: This will be confusing to the user to update the text whenever they type. I suggest setting the textField's placeholder to KG. Also by updating the textfield's text, it would make it hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

initially clear the value when begin start

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
textField.text = ""
}
```

when editing is over append the kg

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
yourTextfieldName.text = "\(textField.text!) KG"
}
```

**Choice-2**

```
 func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) 
{
if !textField.text!.rangeOfString("KG").location != NSNotFound {
self.textField.text = textField.text!.stringByAppendingString("KG")
 }
}
```

Comment: I am not familier with swift but we can do in this way

Comment: This is what i have been looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a "Label" next to the UITextField.

And then just change the text of the Label to whatever the user selects.

OR (but i dont know if that works), try to get the text form the textfield, add the unit (as a string) to the string from the textfield.

Comment: I have tried it but because of the stupid design i couldnt manage it. If there is no way to do it, i must place a label as you said.  Just looking for better programmatical way. Thanks for advice.